# Autocomplete users lastname in PHP form selection field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have tried to search for an answer, but I don't know the exact terms to use.
I'm sorry if this has been asked (a lot) before.

I have an HTML/PHP form where the user needs to enter a client name via dropdown field.
What I want to do with this field is limit the selection while the user is typing. Say I want to input the name John Smith, wich is shown as "Smith, john", I want the user to be able to start typing the last name and the form 'automatically' select the name closest to what has been typed already.
So in this example I would type in "Smit" and the dropdown list is limited to all names that start with 'Smit'.

I know HTML and PHP, but Java/jQuery/AJAX/etc are new for me and I really don't know where/how to start ;-)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: 
I have tried the javascript autocomplete function. The examples given seem to work quite well, although it now presents an ugly list of words that match.

What I'm still not sure about is how to get a PHP array in there. I have tried to do what void suggests, but to no avail. Here's the code I have now:

```
<script>
var client= $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($clname); ?>);

$(function(){
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: client
    });
});
</script>
```

Where $clname is an array of 'lastname, firstname' entries from my client table.

Comment: The control you're looking for is an 'autocomplete': http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: There is an element provided by **Jquery UI** library which is exactly what you need, take a look at : http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ for further information. **EDIT** @RoryMcCrossan has been faster than me !

Comment: Try this: http://mattmorz.blogspot.com/2015/02/typeahead-implementation-in-phpmysql.html

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, I will look into it and report back here.

Comment: @Renz Since it seems [void](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28537324/369450) answered your question, you should mark it as accepted, and then ask a new supplementary asking about how fix the "ugly list of words".

Comment: Just did, sorry. Although it looks to be the answer, I cannot get it to work. I'll go look into that then ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`autocomplete`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) provided by `jQuery UI`

I am assuming you have an `Array` of names in `PHP` then you can do it this way

```
<script>
var username= $.parseJSON('<?php echo json_encode($username); ?>'); // Convert PHP Array to JS Array

// DOM Ready
$(function() {
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: username
    });
  });
</script>
```

Or you can also make an `AJAX` call to fetch `array` from `PHP`.

Dont forget to include `jquery-ui.js`